# Are there any functions to check the angle of polygon?

Tags: polygon, geometry, intersection, jts-topology-suite

I have 2 polygons that are connecting each other at a line like this. I want to remove overlaps between 2 polygons for which I see a function `difference` in JTS which works nicely but I want to apply it to the polygon which is more curvier.
I was thinking of converting polygon to linestring and then calculate the angle of line but don't seem to find exact function for doing so.

[image]

Comment: How would you define a 'curvy' polygon? There are ways to convert a polygon to a line (search for instance *polygon centerline*), but those will usually not work well for polygons that have a rounded shape, rather than elongated. Out of curiosity, why do you want this?

Comment: Assume these polygons as road and one side lane is connecting to the main road. l want to remove overlap from the side lane instead of main road.

Comment: curvy polygon from above image on the left which is not straight if we compare with another.

Comment: Don't the roads have an attribute that identifies side lanes and main roads?

Comment: I do but in some cases I get similar attribute like in the case of adjacent roads. There I need to play with the geometry.